# $\langle x^a, y^b\rangle $ is an irreducible ideal in $K[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Prove that $\langle x^a, y^b\rangle$ is an irreducible ideal in $K[x,y]$.

Any kind of help is very much welcomed.

Comment: $K= \mathbb R or   \mathbb C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every ideal $I$ that properly contains $\langle x^a,y^b \rangle$ must have a non-zero polynomial $p(x,y) \in I$ where all terms in $p$ are of the form $kx^cy^d$ where both $0 \leq c < a$ and $0 \leq d < b$.  Consider $q = x^{\beta}p \in I$ where the smallest power of $x$ appearing in the terms of $q$ is $a-1$. All terms with powers of $x$ that are $\geq a$ can be removed from $q$ to obtain $r \in I$, since $x^a \in I$. Then similarly put $s = y^{\gamma}r$ so that the smallest power of $y$ appearing in the terms of $s$ is $b-1$, and when you remove all the  terms whose power of $y$ is $\geq b$, you are left with $k'x^{a-1}y^{b-1} \in I$, so $x^{a-1}y^{b-1} \in I$. Since $I$ is arbitrary, this shows that any intersection of ideals that properly contain $\langle x^a,y^b \rangle$ must also contain $x^{a-1}y^{b-1}$, which is clearly not an element of $\langle x^a,y^b \rangle$. Thus $\langle x^a,y^b \rangle$ is irreducible.